# Accessing a property of a subclass with an array of the base class

Tags: c#, properties, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game in Unity, and have come across an issue with accessing a subclass property.

I have a base class called "Component" that is only used to group together all the subclasses that inherit it.  I have a "Track" class that inherits from Component that has some public properties.

```
public class Track : Component {

    public int x;
    public int y;

}
```

Another class keeps an array of Components and makes changes to them.

```
public class Example: MonoBehaviour {

    private Component[] components = new Component[10];

    void Start () {

        components[0] = new Track();
        components[0].x = 5; //Does not compile

    }
}
```

I am unsure of how to access the properties in Track with an array of the base class Component.  I appreciate any help anyone can provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure it's a `Track`, you could cast it to that type:

```
components[0] = new Track();

((Track)components[0]).x = 5;
```

In this case, you're sure it's a `Track` because you just instantiated it.

But if it's possible other classes could also inherit from `Component`, and that your `components` collection may not have instances of `Track`, you'll want to check first before doing the assignment.

```
var track = components[0] as Track;

if (track != null)
    track.x = 5;
```

Comment: Correct it needs explicit typecast but you need to beware of the run time issues, second version using as operator would be a better choice, since it will not throw exception in any scenario and just needs null check

Comment: Thanks, Grant.  It appears I was missing a few parenthesis when trying to cast on my own.  I have solved the issue with your solution!